# To get Stable Keyboard Configs for 90 WPM and Dvorak in Debian?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am trying to set stable keyboard configurations for the user with 90 WPM of correct words per minute and the keyboard layout Dvorak. 
The cursor location is behaving unstably for instance in editors when typing in Debian 8.1, much differently than in OSX. 
The cursor also inactivates sometimes suddenly where the test with the typeracer confirms that: the cursor inactivates at the start of each game in any browsers: Google-chrome used here as a benchmark.

### Settings

I disabled every keybinding in `Keyboard > Shortcuts` such that no effect on my typing anymore. 
However, still unstable keyboard behaviour is occurring. 
My keyboard config is the following by which I can reach 95-105 WPM in single games but not on average because the keyboard cursor is moving unstably, particularly at the start of the typeracer -game used as another benchmark here.

[image]

### Typeracer -test in many games

It occurs sometimes that at the start of the game, the cursor location is not active. 
You need to press the mouse to the box to get active again.

### Problem in Editors such as gedit

The typeracer -problem is duplicating in standard text editors. 
The cursor moves suddenly from the original location to somewhere random location.

Why does the cursor location changes after each game in [typingracer](http://play.typeracer.com/) in any browser of Linux?
How can you make the typing more stable in Debian 8.1?
What is causing the sudden changes in the cursor position?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a keyboard issue; there's no reason a cursor should move to random locations during usage. Are you typing on a laptop? could your arm or palm be brushing the trackpad, causing the cursor to re-locate itself?

Comment: @KlaatuvonSchlacker Yes, typing with laptop. Not a arm or palm brushing problem with trackpad. I think it is the issue with some low-grade laptops and their touchpads. Bad driver support.